# Loading all contacts using the Microsoft Graph API sometimes looses/skips pages

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

We have an application that loads all contacts stored in an account using the Microsoft Graph API. The initial call we issue is [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/contacts$count=true&$orderBy=displayName%20ASC&$top=100](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserPrincipalName%7D/contacts$count=true&$orderBy=displayName%20ASC&$top=100), but we use the Java JDK to do that. Then we iterate over all pages and store all loaded contacts in a Set (local cache).

We do this every 5 minutes using an account with over 3000 contacts and sometimes, the count of contacts we received due to using $count does not match the number of contacts we loaded and stored in the local cache.

Verifying the numbers manually we can say, that the count was always correct, but there are contacts missing.

We use the following code to achieve this.

```
public List<Contact> loadContacts() {
    Set<Contact> contacts = new TreeSet<>((contact1, contact2) -> StringUtils.compare(contact1.id, contact2.id));

    List<QueryOption> requestOptions = List.of(
            new QueryOption("$count", true),
            new QueryOption("$orderBy", "displayName ASC"),
            new QueryOption("$top", 100)
    );

    ContactCollectionRequestBuilder pageRequestBuilder = null;
    ContactCollectionRequest pageRequest;
    boolean hasNextPage = true;

    while (hasNextPage) {
        // initialize page request
        if (pageRequestBuilder == null) {
            pageRequestBuilder = graphClient.users(userId).contacts();
            pageRequest = pageRequestBuilder.buildRequest(requestOptions);
        } else {
            pageRequest = pageRequestBuilder.buildRequest();
        }

        // load
        ContactCollectionPage contactsPage = pageRequest.get();
        if (contactsPage == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("request returned a null page");
        } else {
            contacts.addAll(contactsPage.getCurrentPage());
        }

        // handle next page
        hasNextPage = contactsPage.getNextPage() != null;
        if (hasNextPage) {
            pageRequestBuilder = contactsPage.getNextPage();
        } else if (contactsPage.getCount() != null && !Objects.equals(contactsPage.getCount(), (long) contacts.size())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("loaded %d contacts but response indicated %d contacts", contacts.size(), contactsPage.getCount()));
        } else {
            // done
        }
    }

    log.info("{} contacts loaded using graph API", contacts.size());

    return new ArrayList<>(contacts);
}
```

Initially, we did not put the loaded contacts in a Set by ID but just in a List. With the List we very often got **more** contacts than $count. My idea was, that there is some caching going on and some pages get fetched multiple times. Using the Set we can make sure, that we only have unique contacts in our local cache.

But using the Set, we sometimes have **less** contacts than $count, meaning some pages got skipped and we end up in the condition that throws the `IllegalStateException`.

Currently, we use microsoft-graph 5.8.0 and azure-identiy 1.4.2.

Have you experienced similar issues and can help us solve this problem?
Or do you have any idea what could be causing these inconsistent results?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you also notice similar behavior leveraging Graph Explorer?

Comment: Hi @Shweta
No I did not but I did not use the Graph Explorer as often as we use the SDK. Keep in mind we load the contacts using the SDK every 5 minutes.